# Como criar um relatório com parâmetros Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Como criar um relatório com parâmetros no Crystal Reports? Criar o relatório pra mim não tem problemas, porém agora eu necessito filtra-lo de acordo de alguns parâmetros da tabela do sistema.

Alguém pode me ajudar com algum exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples utilizar parâmetros para utilizar como filtro:

1. Botão direito em Parameter Field > New...
2. Preencha os valores necessários. Por exemplo, para um filtro de Data Inicial (básico):

> ```
> "NOME": DataInicial
> "TIPO": Data
> "LISTA DE VALORES": Estático
> ```

3. Botão direito no relatório > Report > Select Expert > Record...
4. Selecione o campo a ser filtrado com o parâmetro Data Inicial > OK
5. Na caixa de seleção onde está escrito "qualquer valor", selecione "Maior ou igual a" e no campo em frente digite o nome do parâmetro criado entre {?PARAMETRO}, no exemplo ficaria assim: {?DataInicial}

Pronto, filtro feito.

Answer (score -1):

Que fonte(s) de dados está usando ?

Dependendo da Fonte de Dados, uma Stored Procedure por exemplo, o CR cria os parâmetros.

Fora isto, numa query, basta criar os parâmetros (Lista de Parâmetros)

Fora isto, Explorar de campo, Parâmetro, Novo

A questão é vincular á algum Filtro, mas isto depende da Fonte de Dados

=================

Sim, mas em algum lugar se precisa filtrar senão não faz sentido ter um parâmetro.

Formulas de Selecao __Registro

Comment: Então, eu estou usando uma base de dados do Oracle normal. Eu linkei, criei o parametro e até atribui o valor no momento de execução. Mas não sei se precisa de algo a mais. Não foi feito uma comparação para que haja um filtro de informações, eu simplesmente criei o parametro e atribui o seu valor.